# VBScript: Passing a parameter with a null value to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, parameters, ado

In VBScript (ASP environment), is it possible to pass a parameter with a null value to a stored procedure?

Comment: Burnt, can you provide some sample code on how you'd like to pass nulls... inline string building or typed parameters on your ADO Command object?

Answer (score 10):

Passing null to a stored procedure, using a command object.

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=.\Test"
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "TestTable.sp_ModifyData"
cmd.CommandType = 4
cmd.NamedParameters = True

set cnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("@RowID",3,3,,-1)
cmd.Parameters.Append cnParam
set cnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("@AddRemoveModify",3,1,,0)
cmd.Parameters.Append cnParam
set cnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("@Value1",3,1,,0)
cmd.Parameters.Append cnParam
set cnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("@Value2",8,1,-1,"Test")
cmd.Parameters.Append cnParam
set cnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("@value3",5,1,,null)
cmd.Parameters.Append cnParam
set cnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("@value4",5,1,,0)
cmd.Parameters.Append cnParam
set cnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("@value5",8,1,-1,"")
cmd.Parameters.Append cnParam
cmd.Execute
cn.Close
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Sorry I didn't put much thought into naming the fields in my database.

Answer (score 5):

Try vbNullString or vbNullChar. You may also need adParamNullable.

```
set cnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("@value3",5,1,,vbNullString)  
cnParam.Attributes = adParamNullable  
cmd.Parameters.Append cnParam
```

Update:

Actually this worked for me:

```
set cnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("@value3",5,1,,Null)  
cnParam.Attributes = adParamNullable  
cmd.Parameters.Append cnParam
```

Huh, this worked too:

```
set cnParam = cmd.CreateParameter("@value3",5,1,,Null)  
cmd.Parameters.Append cnParam
```

Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

If you're building strings, and checking/guarding against SQL Injection,  you can simply use the word null in your SQL string, or comma delimited EXEC statement.

```
'calling a stored proc.
strSQL = "EXEC UpdateCustomer @CustomerID=" & iCustomerID + ",@PhoneNumber=null"
```

Here's how to use null in a manually built string to send to the DB

```
strSQL = "UPDATE Customer SET PhoneNumber = null WHERE CustomerID = " + iCustomerID
```

Comment: Unfortunately i have to use stored procedure to maintain consistency in my project. Is there a way that i can use stored procedures?

Comment: @Burnt: are you able to edit your question to show how you're using stored procedures? The answer here shows one way to use stored procedures, perhaps you're using another way. Please include some code, it'll definitely help.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Set the parameter value to `Null` (VBScript keyword).