# Null string causing type mismatch

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, ado

I'm writing an old asp page to insert Session variables into a database to transfer them to an ASP.NET application. So I'm looping through them and using a stored procedure to insert them into the db. One them has a null string as a value and when inserting those it fails with :

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch

I have Wrote them out to the page in the form as key=value=vartype and the vartype is indeed 8, a string. Its the GoBack line that fails:

```
User_id=2029=8
GoBack==8
ID_Reps=12345726=8
```

Here is the call:

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@SessionValue", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4000, Session(objItem))
```

I would rather not convert it to an empty string when inserting. Is there a way around this?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159796/vbscript-passing-a-parameter-with-a-null-value-to-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up making the parameter optional with a null default and bypassing adding it if the value was null.

Answer (score 0):

Two options would be replacing Session(objItem) with either:

```
If(Session(objItem), DBNull.Value)
```

or

```
If(Session(objItem), String.Empty)
```